# FreqDist.plot not using the most common words

Tags: nltk

I am following the code in http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html specifically section 3.2.

```
from __future__ import division
import nltk
from nltk.book import *
import dateutil
import pyparsing
import numpy
import six
import matplotlib
fdist1 = FreqDist(text1)
fdist1.plot(50,cumulative=True)
```

is the script that I am running (the future import is leftover from some other stuff). However the plot I get does not match the one in the book. It has uncommon words such as funereal. I am running 32bit python 2.7 on windows. My friend who is running it on his mac runs the same commands and gets the plot from the book. I am at a complete loss as to what the difference may be. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you define tex1? (The book calls FreqDist() on text1)

Comment: Typo, I was mainly running this in the python command line and I just wrote the code to mirror what I was running.

Comment: What happens when you print the contents of text1? Can you verify your text1 = your friend's text1?

Comment: Yes they are the same. fdist1.most_common(50) correctly returns the 50 most common words, which are equivalent to my friends 50 most common words. The plot doesn't plot those words though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently had the same problem.

NLTK builds it `FreqDist` upon the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class from python's `collections` package. The `plot()` (and the `tabulate()` function) extract the samples to use as follows:

```
samples = list(islice(self, *args))
```

Source: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/probability.html

I guess they're doing it that way to enable plotting of sub-sequences like the range between the 10th and the 40th sample, but it assumes that the Counter object (which basically is a `dict`) is sorted. Though that sometimes is the case, it obviously does not always hold, as the python documentation explicitely states. The correct replacement for the above line in the NLTK source would be:

```
samples = [item for item, _ in self.most_common(*args)]
```

That correct version can be also found in the most recent [NLTK code on GitHub](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/probability.py). It has been fixed in NLTK 3.0.0, so make sure that you aren't using an older version (like an alpha or beta version of NLTK 3).

If you do not want to change the source of NLTK and can not update it, you could easily adapt the `plot()` function yourself:

```
def plot_freqdist(fd, num = 0, cumulative = False, title = None):
    import pylab
    # Set up parameters
    if num <= 0:
        num = fd.B
    # Get samples and frequencies
    samples, freq, accu = [], [], 0
    for s, f in fd.most_common(num):
        accu = accu + f if cumulative else f
        samples.append(s)
        freq.append(accu)
    # Create plot
    pylab.grid(True, color = 'silver')
    if title:
        pylab.title(title)
    pylab.plot(freq, linewidth = 2)
    pylab.xticks(range(len(samples)), samples, rotation = 90)
    pylab.xlabel('Samples')
    pylab.ylabel('Cumulative Counts' if cumulative else 'Counts')
    pylab.show()
```